# Мигание цвета кнопки

Tags: jquery, html

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как сделать мигание цвета кнопки, а то у меня ток один раз мигнет и остановится.

```
$(function () {
    $("#Button").css("color", "black");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Button").css("color", "black");
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#Button").css("color", "green");
        }, 500)
    }, 3000);
});
```

-

```
<a id="Button" href="#"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, у вас перебор с функциями, но оставлю как есть, и вот мой вариант:

```
$(function () {
    var flag = false;
    $("#Button").css("color", "black");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Button").css("color", "black");
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#Button").css("color", flag? "black":"green");
            flag = !flag;
        }, 500)
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Да, спасибо заработало!

Answer (score 0):

```
function startcolor {
 var coloring = true
 while(coloring = true) {
 $("#Button").css("color", "black");
    setTimeout(function () {
        $("#Button").css("color", "black");
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#Button").css("color", "green");
        }, 500)
    }, 3000);
 }
}

function stopColor() {
 coloring = false;
}
```

Начало мигания будит вызываться командой startColor(), а конец stopColor()

Comment: получаеться, что бесконечный цикл

Comment: @Сергей_666 Ага, который останавливается функцией stopColor(). А если хотите, чтобы он никому не мешал пустите его через web workers

Comment: Только при запуске первой функции, перезагружаеться браузер, а до второй функции дело не доходит